# What are the general strategies in creating a Probabilistic Graphical Model?

Tags: machine-learning, references, prediction, graphical-model

While there is lot of theory and probability in the background to understand, I wanted to know if there are any resources/quick pointers on what to consider while modeling a problem using Bayesian Networks.

Specifically, I had the following questions:
- what kind of priors to use?
- what do we learn from the data? and how to do prediction?

Is there a blog/document that explains these from the ground-up with simple use-cases?
(eg: modeling user-click behavior, weather forecasting, diagnosis etc). I am looking for examples which are a little detailed beyond toy-examples (a bit close to real life situations) used in courses.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0082349) explains the design stages of a Bayesian Network based on a real-life data-set and for a real-life application. It touches on pre-processing data, how to learn the probability space (MLE - which is simple), how to learn the DAG's (which I refer to as causal discovery), what to take into account while learning the DAGs, etc.

I am happy to provide more information if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be reading research papers that use those models for some task. I assume that this task will most often be classification.

I know of one book about applications of BNs:

- *Bayesian network technologies: applications and graphical models*.
  Mittal, Ankush and Kassim, Ashraf, **2007**, IGI

Concerning Markov networks, you can look for applications using *Markov logic*. ML is some modeling language for Markov networks, and there exist some applications, for example:

- *Goal-based person tracking using a first-order probabilistic model*
  T Geier, S Reuter, K Dietmayer, S Biundo - Proceedings of the Ninth UAI … Workshop, **2012**
- *Event modeling and recognition using markov logic networks*.
  SD Tran, LS Davis - Computer Vision–ECCV 2008, **2008** - Springer
- *Goal Recognition with Markov Logic Networks for Player-Adaptive Games*.
  EY Ha, JP Rowe, BW Mott, JC Lester - AIIDE, **2011** - aaai.org
- *Recognizing Multi-Agent Activities from GPS Data*.
  A Sadilek, HA Kautz - AAAI, **2010** - aaai.org

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Coursera course](https://class.coursera.org/pgm/lecture/preview) on Probabilistic Graphical Models.
Though there isn't any future session announced, you can still watch the videos